# How can you change the rotation of a mirror modifier?

Tags: mirror

I am trying to use the mirror modifier on a cylinder I rotated and edited, but when I apply said modifier it mirrors based off its original angle rather than the new one. How can I fix this?[image]

Comment: did you apply rotation (ctrl+A)? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data

Comment: Yeah the rotation was in Object Mode

Comment: Actually this is one of those times when you don't want to apply the rotation.  Mirror modifier works off local axes, so if you rotate then apply you will change the mirror axis.  Either leave the rotation unapplied or add a Mirror Object to the modifier so it knows where the mirror plane should be.

Answer (score 7):

This is not a direct solution to your problem (that really sounds like an "Apply rotation" problem), but it is a work-around that might allow you to achieve what you want.

1. Remove the `Mirror` modifier and instead add an `Array` modifier.
2. Add an `Empty` at the location of the original object.
3. Set the `Empty` as `Object Offset` in the `Array` modifier.
4. Rotate the `Empty` until you get a desired rotation.

Comment: not sure why but all that did for me was make a crazy offset extrusion

Answer (score 5):

If you use an empty as the rotation *Mirror Object:* in the *Mirror* Object modifier, you can use the empty's rotation to affect the mirror. Procedure described at 4:30 [here](https://youtu.be/BPM_k8BY-dY?t=266).